# c# single worker thread, single GUI thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010

I have several forms applications, that rely on worker threads to do all the processing. They talk to an external application that in some cases relies on simulating user interface (copy/paste functionality).

In each case I have a RichTextBox in the form, to provide feedback to the user during progressing - which needs to be async so that the textbox can update in real time. (disclaimer: this was my first dive into the world of threading and async processes, the feedback part works at least!)

I have a class "AppTrack" that is being used to monitor all these applications for usage, reporting, and better exception handling. In it are 2 functions (shown below) I use to fire the worker threads "safely", along with turning on/off certain form controls to prevent further user interaction.

```
    public static void DoInSafeThread(Action ActualThreadFunction, List<Control> FormControls = null)
    {

        System.Action<System.Exception> exception = null;
        Thread thread = new Thread(
            () => AppTrack.SafeExecute(() => ActualThreadFunction(), exception, FormControls)
            );
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();
    }
    private static void SafeExecute(Action ActualThreadFunction, Action<Exception> handler, List<Control> FormControls)
    {
        try
        {
            DisableControls(FormControls);
            ActualThreadFunction.Invoke();
            EnableControls(FormControls);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Handler(ex);
        }
    }
```

This is causing me a big problem if there is a list of things to process, like the snippet below. It will fire a new worker thread for each one, and the nature of the interface with the external application means the processes interfere and give bad results/errors.

```
foreach (IOccurrences s in sel)
{
    AppTrack.DoInSafeThread(delegate()
     {
         CableChecking.CheckCables((IOccurrences)s, rtbLog, CableData, materials);
     }, FormControls);

}
```

### Thoughts on solution

Have a single thread used in my "AppTrack" class. Assign it a new operation as it completes the previous one, or queue them up to run in order and eventually feedback to the GUI thread that all jobs are complete. But, trying to implement that I hit a brick wall... Is this even the correct approach?

I was hoping to find things like thread.BindNewAction but, that's apparently not right...

Comment: *Don't* use a thread, use a single `await Task.Run()` to run a single job, or an `ActionBlock<T>` if you want to pump messages to a worker for processing

Comment: BTW the earliest supported .NET version is 4.5.2. If you use VS2010 it means you're targeting an *unsupported* runtime that probably doesn't exist in production. The .NET 4.x versions are binary replacements which means that machines that started with 4.0 were upgraded to 4.5 or later through Windows Upgrade sometime in the last 9 years

Comment: Check Stephen Toub's [Async in 4.5: Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/) to see how you can use `Progress<T>` to report events from other threads or tasks. Even in .NET 4.0 though, you can use Task with ContinueWith and concurrent collections like ConcurrentQueue to post work to the worker and have the continuation run on the UI thread